# Selecting data from column that has csv mysql

Tags: php, mysql

Fairly simple one but struggling with it, I have a table which has a column in it called 'teams' some of the rows have multiple teams and are comma separated so one guy might have `team1, team2` and another may have `team2,team3,team4`.

What I want to do is perform a `SELECT` query so that if one person has `team1` and another has `team1` it outputs them both despite having other teams in that column.

Here is how the basis of my query looks:

```
$sql = "SELECT * FROM respondant_data WHERE respondant_team = 'Central Team'";
$result = $conn->query($sql);

if($result->num_rows > 0){
    while($row = $result->fetch_assoc()){
        echo $row["respondant_firstname"];
        echo $row["respondant_lastname"];
        echo $row["respondant_team"];
        echo '<br>';        
    }
} else{
    echo 'no results';
}
```

And as you can guess it returns nothing back to me because all users that have 'Central Team' have other teams in their column too.

** UPDATE **

So as per suggestion below I have made an update to my query:

```
$sql = "SELECT * FROM respondant_data WHERE FIND_IN_SET('Central Team', respondant_team) > 0";
```

So it does return some data but not all, so it's returning the people with a single value in the column still.

Comment: You should really change your table design. It is not normalized. Never store multiple values in a single column!!

Comment: The issue I have is that this data is loaded in via a CSV by my client, im seriously limited as they are not willing to change their data format

Comment: Then have a look at `find_in_set()`

Comment: Can I use that agains string values?

Comment: @juergend I have made an update to my question can you check it out for me?

Comment: I'd be tempted to find a new client. That aside, see http://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/333952/why-should-i-provide-an-mcve-for-what-seems-to-me-to-be-a-very-simple-sql-query

Comment: @Strawberry well..... How would you propose re jigging this if they are uploading a csv file initially to get the data from, so they have people, teams and scores against areas

Comment: BTW you need to remove the spaces from your field like `team1, team2`. Use `FIND_IN_SET('Central Team', replace(respondant_team, ' ', '')) > 0`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
 This solution provides you an case-insensitiv text search and prints every Member who is in team 1:  



$YOURNEEDLE = 'team 1';
                $sql = "SELECT * FROM respondant_data WHERE respondant_team = 'Central Team'";
                $result = $conn->query($sql);
                if($result->num_rows > 0){
                    while($row = $result->fetch_assoc()){
                        if(stristr($row["respondant_team"],$YOURNEEDLE)) {
                            echo $row["respondant_firstname"];
                            echo $row["respondant_lastname"];
                            echo $row["respondant_team"];
                            echo '<br>';
                        }
                    }
                } else{
                    echo 'no results';
                }
```

There are many waysd to solve your question, another on:

```
            $needle = 'team 1';
            $sql = "SELECT * FROM respondant_data WHERE respondant_team = 'Central Team'";
            $result = $conn->query($sql);
            if($result->num_rows > 0){
                while($row = $result->fetch_assoc()){
                 $arrayTeams  =     explode(', ',$row["respondant_team"]);
                    if(in_array($needle, $arrayTeams)) {
                        echo $row["respondant_firstname"];
                        echo $row["respondant_lastname"];
                        echo $row["respondant_team"];
                        echo '<br>';
                    }
                }
            } else{
                echo 'no results';
            }
```

Comment: Why i received down vote? Please tell whats the error? Otherwise i couldnt help you?

Answer (score -1):

not best but should work

```
SELECT * FROM respondant_data WHERE respondant_team RLIKE 'Central Team(?:,|$)'
```

so build query in php like this

```
$sql = 'SELECT * FROM respondant_data WHERE respondant_team RLIKE \''.$yourteamname.'(?:,|$)\'';
```